# How to manage multiple repositories in TortoiseSVN

Tags: windows, svn, tortoisesvn

I have two repositories in xp-dev with different user name and password, and i have configured TortoiseSVN svn url with the one repository, and i have folder in my file system, i am doing commit and update.

Now, i want a another folder to use other repository location, So how to have two folders synchronized with the two repositories in TortoiseSVN.

Comment: I've been reading this for several minutes and I still can't extract any sense. Do you want to keep two repositories in synch?

Answer (score 2):

Just checkout second URL with corresponding username and password and verify results. If first user have not rights in second repo, you can even don't supply this information on start - you'll get request (after failed login)

I can't see any traces of problem exploration in your question. What you done? What was bad?

**PS:** Under `...\Application Data\Subversion\auth` any amount of separate credentials can be stored (and stored really)

**PPS:** you can [read about servers file](http://www.visualsvn.com/support/svnbook/advanced/confarea/) and it's features and use, if you want